# Is there a way to make a more compact answer check

Tags: lua

I'm very new to coding and right now my code is really bulky and I want to know if there is a way to make a more compact function to check answers, right now I just have if then statements copied and pasted over and over with the variable capitalized and spelled a different way every time, for example, for no I have if then statements for N,n,no,NO,No,nO.

```
local men = io.read()
if men == "N" then 
    print(" You decide that you're fine with getting pushed around for your whole life, so you continue like that until you are old and die. THE END")
    return
end
if men == "NO" then 
    print(" You decide that you're fine with getting pushed around for your whole life, so you continue like that until you are old and die. THE END")
    return
end
if men == "no" then 
    print(" You decide that you're fine with getting pushed around for your whole life, so you continue like that until you are old and die. THE END")
    return
end
if men == "No" then 
    print(" You decide that you're fine with getting pushed around for your whole life, so you continue like that until you are old and die. THE END")
    return
end
if men == "n" then 
    print(" You decide that you're fine with getting pushed around for your whole life, so you continue like that until you are old and die. THE END")
    return
end
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use  [patterns](https://www.lua.org/pil/20.2.html).  They are very similar to regular expressions which are used across most programming languages.  Here I test the answer string to see if it matches the pattern you're looking for.  Here's an explanation of pattern:

- `^` - match the start of the string, don't allow any characters before this.  If you don't include this then it could find 'no' later in the string, i.e. `abcdNO`
- `[nN]` - the `[]` let you include a list of acceptable characters, so here the first character needs to be `n` or `N`
- `[oO]?` - the next character has to be `o` or `O`, but the `?` means it is optional, it can occur 0 or 1 times.
- `$` matches the end of the string, so it will not match 'NOabcd` because there can't be anything after your pattern.

In all that means the string has to start with 'n' or 'N', possibly have a single 'o' or 'O', and have nothing else after that.

`string.find(string, pattern)` will see if string is matched by pattern and return the position it was found in the string, or `nil` if not found.

```lua
local answer = 'No'
local pattern = '^[nN][oO]?$'
if (string.find(answer, pattern) ~= nil) then 
  print('found!')
else
  print('not found!')
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(abstract_data_type)) then you check if the input is a member of the set. a simple set in Lua can be defined like so:

```lua
local no = {
    N = true,
    n = true,
    no = true,
    NO = true,
    No = true,
    nO = true
}
```

and you use it just by indexing it like any table:

```lua
local men = io.read()
if no[men] then
    print(" You decide that you're fine with getting pushed around for your whole life, so you continue like that until you are old and die. THE END")
    return
end
```

a `nil` in lua will be treated as a `false` in this context, and you will get `nil` from any value that is not a key in the set

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding another answer to offer a simpler change.  You should generally try to find a way to avoid duplicate code.  The same 'print' statement is repeated several times.

One thing you can do is use the [or operator](https://www.lua.org/pil/3.3.html) and combine all your tests into one expression.

```lua
local men = io.read()
if men == "N" or men == "NO" or men == "no" or men == "No" or men == "n" then 
    print(" You decide that you're fine with getting pushed around for your whole life, so you continue like that until you are old and die. THE END")
    return
end
```

That is the best method for the setup you have, but if you don't have a simple condition like this and want to reuse the code you could create a function with the duplicated code and call it instead.  Say if you wanted to do something ELSE as well depending on certain values:

```lua
function badEnding()
    print(" You decide that you're fine with getting pushed around for your whole life, so you continue like that until you are old and die. THE END")
    -- NOTE: return is not required, the default return value will be nil
end

local men = io.read()
if men == "N" then return badEnding() end
if men == "NO" then 
    print("Hey, no need to shout!")
    return badEnding()
end
if men == "no" then return badEnding() end
if men == "No" then return badEnding() end
if men == "n" then return badEnding() end
```

Answer (score -2):

You can put your options into a list and than ask through a for-loop if your input is equal to a statement in your list. If not there isn't a mistake.

For example if you have list like:

```
l_words = ["N","n","no","NO","N0","nO"]

inp = input("Your input: ")

for i in l_words:
    if inp != i:
        print("true input")
    else:
        print("false input")
```

Comment: that is not `Lua`, this question is tagged with the `Lua` programming language.